# Flexbox: How to write a simple responsive side-by-side article layout?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Simple idea: 2 articles side by side, unless their width is below a threshold (e.g. 400px) in which case the articles get arranged vertically. Either way the content should fill the width of the viewport.

The snippet below is partially right. Each article is 49% of the viewport width, with a min-width of 400px, so if the viewport is below 2x400px (give or take a few pixels) the articles are arranged vertically. However then they only get 49% of the viewport width, which is bad when they are arranged vertically. This is where I'm stuck. Thoughts?

Thanks!

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.contentPanel {
  border: 1px solid goldenrod;
  min-width: 400px;
  width: 49vw;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<body>
  <!-- Main Area -->
  <div class='main'>
    <div class="contentPanel">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
    <div class="contentPanel">
      Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
      one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus
      Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line
      in section 1.10.32.
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: flex-grow:1 to articles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flex:1 1 200px;` Which means:

1. `flex-grow:1;` **Grow when there's space**
2. `flex-shrink:1;` **Shrink to fit**
3. `flex-basis:200px;` **If the container width is below `400px` wrap**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.contentPanel {
  border: 1px solid ;
  flex: 1 1 200px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Main Area -->
<div class='main'>
  <div class="contentPanel">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
  <div class="contentPanel">
    Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
    one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
    et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section
    1.10.32.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Zohir.

Comment: Btw it looks like the spec is wrong about flex-grow defaulting to 1 when omitted. Actually it's self-contradictory; https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-property says the default value for flex is "0 1 auto" but then later says flex-grow "When omitted, it is set to 1." I confirmed locally that omitting flex-grow doesn't work; I have to set it to 1.

Comment: The spec is not wrong, that section talks about the flex shorthand, When `flex-grow` is omitted in the shorthand in cases like `flex:1 10px;` or `flex:10px;`

Comment: Ah ok ... so if you omit grow in the `flex` shorthand it defaults to 1, but if you don't specify `flex` or `flex-grow` it defaults to 0. Interesting choices.